# Have webpack-dev-middleware serve index html only for routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure how to use webpack-dev-middleware. Specifically, it's trying to serve my index HTML for every file--including JS bundles, manifest.json, etc.

Using webpack-dev-server this can be addressed using historyApiFallback, but unless I'm mistaken that doesn't work for webpack-dev-middleware.

Since the server doesn't know from the request whether the URL is a route URL or a resource URL, the handler can't know out of the box whether to serve the index html.

I can think of a couple of ways to address this; neither particularly clean:

1. Keep routes in a place that both the client code and the server code can access it, so that the server can determine whether a route is requested or some other resource. Of course, the server won't necessarily know about React components (unless it's doing SSR, I guess), so you'd presumably need to separate the route definitions from their rendered elements. You'd also need to convert dynamic parts of routes (e.g. from react-router) to something that the server (e.g. Express) can recognize.
2. Make sure that everything you serve that is *not* a route is in a particular subdirector(y|ies). Then, your request handler can ignore anything in those subdirectories. This means that all js bundles, all CSS bundles, images, fonts, etc. are served from some known directory or directories.

Number 2 seems like the better option, but it still requires being very careful about where things get served from. Am I missing something?